# cordova camera plugin getting real path of selected image

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

```
var options = {
    quality: 30, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(imageURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
            console.log(fileEntry.toURI());
            scope.$apply(function() {    
                ctrl.$setViewValue(fileEntry.fullPath);
            });
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }); 
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }, options
);
```

The imageURI returns '/media/external/images/media/11.

I wanted to get the real path but window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL only returns 'content://media/external/images/media/11'.

I'm trying to get something like '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/camera/321321321.jpg'.

Comment: I'm looking same answer. I'm getting the file as base64. But I need real path to upload it after.
If Base64 image works for you i can post the answer

Comment: Hi @Schwertfisch! i found the solution. Look at my answer below.

Comment: i tried base64 but it's hard to save it into a new file on the mobile device.

Answer (score 5):

I just found the solution. The code change should be done within the plugin, not inside the javascript file.

First find the CameraLauncher.java

Add this function. This is the function that will convert '/media/external/images/media/' to realpath

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Then find this line. This is the one that returns imageURI on navigator.camera.getPicture(success())

```
if (this.targetHeight == -1 && this.targetWidth == -1 &&
        (destType == FILE_URI || destType == NATIVE_URI) && !this.correctOrientation) {
    this.callbackContext.success(uri.toString());
}
```

Change this line to

```
if (this.targetHeight == -1 && this.targetWidth == -1 &&
        (destType == FILE_URI || destType == NATIVE_URI) && !this.correctOrientation) {
    this.callbackContext.success(getRealPathFromURI(uri)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. I'm gonna edit a little your solution.

Comment: I am also have issue even updated the plugin still not able to get image path

Comment: I did that but not working for me. Still no image to preview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `fileEntry.toURL()`

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too.
You must use the [cordova-plugin-filepath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath). It will convert to the real path.

```
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
//FilePath will resolve the path
        window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageUrl, function (result) {
            imageURI = 'file://' + result;
            console.log(imageURI);
            resolve(imageURI);
        });
    });
```

With this you can enable edit (allowEdit: true) or even save on your photolibrary.
Tested and working!

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,mediaType:Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,saveToPhotoAlbum:true,sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    $("#img_id").attr("src",imageData);
    alert(imageData);
}
```

gives output as /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/IMG_9999433.jpg

Answer (score -2):

you ca use this

```
function getImageURI(imageURI) {

var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
    alert("got image file entry: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
    var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {
// your code
```